# Locating Businesses by Latitude and Longitude (API?/Webservice?)

Tags: web-services, geolocation

I am looking for a **free** database (csv, tab delimited, xml, etc) or even a web service or API which will allow me to query for business listings within a certain distance of a latitude and longitude.

A global scope would be perfect, but I would settle for Canada/US information.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: Are you looking for a listing of businesses and their geo locations? What scope - global?

Comment: Yes that would be it, global would be perfect, but I would settle for US/Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Google AJAX search API offers this kind of service (local search) if you use the Google Maps API, see http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/

Apparently Yahoo! does too (see http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/localSearch.html), if you do not plan a commercial use.

Comment: Unfortunately, these require a specific Query which I do not want to provide.

Comment: how do you expect to find the desired results without a query?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this right, here is what you need:

- Database of all locations, with long/lat coords
- Database of all businesses
- Address --> long/lat conversion system, if your business database is not already geocoded

I can't help you out with the business database, but here is a good resource for the "all locations" database:

http://www.geobytes.com/freeservices.htm

(Scroll down to the bottom of the page - you're looking for "GeoWorldMap".)

It contains a set of text files that are designed to be imported into a relational database.  It's the most complete (free) resource that I've been able to find for this sort of task.

Comment: it is not really free...  but pretty cheap ($10)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Places API provides exactly what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search